# PHP Coding of Coupon Code on Checkout Page?

Tags: php, sql

What would be the coding of coupon code on checkout page in PHP coding. I have already made a form, lets suppose my coupon code is ABC, so I write value="ABC" in form. What is the coding of submit button to update grand total?

```
    <form action="checkout1.php" method="post">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Code" name="code" value="abc">
  <button type="submit" name="btn3"><i class="fa fa"></i>Apply Coupon</button>  
  </form>
<?php
      @$cart = unserialize(serialize($_SESSION['cart']));
      $total = 0;
      $quantity = 0;
      if($cart){
      foreach($cart as $k=>$v)
        {


        $total += $v->price * $v->quantity;
        $quantity=$v->quantity;

      ?>


      <p><a href="cart.php">Name: <?php echo $v->name;?><br></a> <span class="price">Rs <?php echo $v->price * $v->quantity;?></span></p>
      <p>QTY: <?php echo $quantity;?></p>

      <?php }     ?>
      <table style="width:80%">
  <tr>
    <th> <p style="margin-top:25px; font-size:15px;">Subtotal:</p></th>
    <th></th> 


    <th><span class="price" style="color:black; "><b>Rs <?php echo $total;?></b></span></th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th> <p style="margin-top:25px; font-size:17px;">GRAND TOTAL:</p></th>
    <th></th> 

        <?php


            if($total < 500){


        ?>
    <th> <span class="price" style="color:black; "><b>Rs  <?php echo $total + 100;?></b></span></th>
   <p>(Delivery charges 100 is added below 500)</p>

    <?php

            }else{

    ?>
     <th> <span class="price" style="color:black; "><b>Rs <?php echo $total;?></b></span></th>

     <?php

            }
     ?>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Result I desire: Whenever a customer submits/applies ABC code, the grand total should be updated (deducting xyz amount/percentage).